# Working with JQuery append and slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble hiding old div after appending the content of that div to a div.I want old div to slide right and show the new div with content every time when i click on add more button.

My Html code:

```
<div id="div_2">
    this is div 2 
    <form class="this_form"> 
        <input type="button" value="buttons"  />
    </form> 
</div>

<div id="show_form">    
</div>

<button class="pull-right" type="button" id="btns">add more</button>
```

This is what I tried so far...
My javascript:

```
$("body").on("click","#btns",function(){
  $("#show_form").append($("#div_2").html()); 
  $('#show_form').hide("slow");
  $('#div_2').show("slow");
} );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please run this code snippet**, I think this is want you want to achieve.

From your question,

**`I want old div to slide right and show the new div with content`**

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").on("click",".btns",function(){
//$(".show_form").html('')
  $(".show_form").append($(".div_2").html()); 
//  $('#div_2').hide("slow");
$('.div_2').animate(
                        {
                            'margin-left':'1000px'
                        },function(){
                            $(".div_2").remove()
                            $('#show_form').attr("id","div_2");
                           $('#div_2').addClass('div_2');
                           $('#div_2').removeClass('show_form');
                            $( "#div_2" ).after(function() {
  return "<div id='show_form' class='show_form'></div>"
});
$('#show_form').addClass('show_form')

                        })
  $('.show_form').show("slow");
} );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div_2" class="div_2">
   this is div 2 
    <form class="this_form"> 
         <input type="button" value="buttons"  />
    </form> 
</div>                 

<div id="show_form" class="show_form">    
</div>
<button class="pull-right btns" type="button" id="btns">add more</button>


</body>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgur6faz/2/)

Comment: No it is not that what i wanted.it is added only once.but i want every time when i click add more button it will append and slide.

Comment: please elaborate your question, you want the same functionality to happen every time?

Comment: yes i want every time when i click add more it will append and slide old div and show new append div.

Comment: I want all append div to show in a pagination.when i click on 2nd page button,1st page will slide and 2nd page will show and show on.please help me out.Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Fiddle may be it can help you -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5apfvqb/9/)

HTML Code -

```
<div id="div_2">
    this is div 2
    <form class="this_form">
        <input type="button" value="buttons" />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="show_form">
</div>
<button class="pull-right" type="button" id="btns">add more</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_2').hide();
});

$("body").on("click", "#btns", function() {
    $("#show_form").html($("#div_2").html());
    $('#show_form').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2500);
    $('#div_2').show("slow");
});
```